# Deserializing XML into objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following XML which I need to deserialize:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<event code="2wuj0ticofhzt" self="/events/2wuj0ticofhzt" revision="1260234836">
  <name>Test Event 2013</name>
  <partner-settings>
    <partner-setting>
      <registration-type code="1yfopbwhk" link="/registration-types/1yfopbwhk" />
        <personnel code="3eclag1dsrjfi">
          <free-badges>unlimited</free-badges>
        </personnel>
        <personnel code="0nxgc6mfec8yh">
          <free-badges>3</free-badges>
       </personnel>
     </partner-setting>
     <partner-setting>
       <registration-type code="1ygg67prw" link="/registration-types/1ygg67prw" />
     </partner-setting>
   </partner-settings>
</event>
```

Here are my classes that I have created. (I only need to deserialize the fields I have in my classes.):

```cs
[XmlRoot("event")]
public class Event
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("partner-settings")]
    public List<PartnerSetting> PartnerSettings { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("partner-setting")]
public class PartnerSetting
{
    [XmlElement("registration-type")]
    public RegistrationType RegistrationType { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("personnel")]
    public List<Personnel> Personnel { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("registration-type")]
public class RegistrationType
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string RegistrationTypeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("personnel")]
public class Personnel
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("free-badges")]
    public int FreeBadges { get; set; }
}
```

When I currently deserialize the above XML it all works except from the `Personnel` object where I get `0` returned when I'm expecting to see `2`.

I'm not doing anything differently when I'm trying to return a personnel list (i.e. XMLArray attribute, return a List) to a partner setting list but for some reason it won't deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the attribute into `XmlElement` to force each element in the list to be rendered as a single XML element:

```
[XmlElement("personnel")]
public List<Personnel> Personnel { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately I'm still getting 0 returned after changing the attribute to XMLArrayItem

Comment: @JonnoLord, please see my edit. I was in a hurry and didn't read the question trough. You should use `XmlElement`, not `XmlArrayItem`.

Comment: Ok so this works for fine for when the partner-setting only contains one personnel but throws an exception (There is an error in XML document) when there are multiple